# When you hectically visit multiple places in a short span of time (when you need to buy something, for example), what do you call it?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, phrasal-verbs

When you hectically visit multiple places in a short span of time (when you need to buy something, for example), what do you call it? Is it called "running around [places]"? Like

> She was [running around] shops trying to find the best present for her fiancee for Christmas.

Comment: scurrying around the shops

Comment: Rushing round the shops? NB Unless 'she' is marrying another woman, it's _fiancé_ (the French masculine form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works well and suggests visiting many shops in a short period of time. (As a comment says,  insert "the" before "shops" in your example.

The context that you supply helps with this interpetation.  If you just said
"She was running around the shops." It wouldn't be clear.  This could just mean "she was exercising by jogging on the High Street."

But the context clarifies your meaning.

Comment: I agree, although I would mention adding "the" to the OP's original version, "She was running around **the** shops".  However this depends on context.